# Django internationalization: prefix_default_language & language redirect

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'm adding internationalization to my Django project. The idea of how it should work is the following:

- When a user enters "/" i.e. the "homepage" we try to get his/her
  language preferences from our session. If it's not our default
  language (EN), we redirect the user to the local version, like /ES/,
  /RU/, /CN/, etc
- If we have no such session data, we check Accept-Language and
  redirect the user to the local version if we support such
- If we don't support user's Accept-Language OR if it's EN - we don't
  redirect user! we just show the "default language"

I.e. all "not default languages" should have their prefixes, but default one won't. Why the default language should have a prefix, right? )))

The issue is, I can't figure out how to set this logic. If I set `prefix_default_language=False` to disable the /EN/ prefix for default language, it also disables the "not default" redirect. I found a package that solves the problem: https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls#behaviour `settings.SOLID_I18N_USE_REDIRECTS = True` but it doesn't work in Django 2+

I can't believe I'm the only one hating the default language prefixes )) Although I could not find any solution with both redirect and no prefix for the default language. Hope someone will advice something here

Comment: OK I solved that writing custom middleware extending and bit changing LocaleMiddleware logic for `prefixed_default_language = False` case. Will put it @ github after testing etc, will update this Q

Comment: Can't you fix django-solid-i18n-urls to work for Django 2.2? It shouldn't be too difficult and I'm sure lots of people would appreciate :-)

Comment: @dirkgroten I will probably end with this instead of my own middleware, right ))