# How to check if the url is not in the i18n_pattern?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-i18n

I need to check if the request path is outside the i18n_pattern, i.e. it should not have 'lang' prefix. For example, I have the following urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('api.urls'), name='api'),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('core.urls'), name='index'),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

The `reverse` for 'api' shows that it will not be prefixed whatever language is used. Are there any other ways to figure out that the path of the current request is not included in `i18n_patterns`? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you need to check that? What are you trying to do? Maybe this is not the right approach.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm extending the functionality of LocaleMiddleware to make it possible combining prefix_default_language=False and language auto-detection (I mentioned this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393364/django-internationalization-prefix-default-language-language-redirect). So the middleware should be able to determine the situations when if shouldn't touch the request/responce like when it's /api/smth request in my example. In my app I temporarly solved that by hardcoding the exceptions but want to find the proper way

Comment: `request.resolver_match` gives you a `ResolverMatch` object, documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch).  With this you can get a `namespace`, maybe if you list your non-translated namespaces somewhere you could check that.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks! this seems to be a good way out

Answer (score 3):

You can check if url is not in the i18n_pattern using `django.urls.LocalePrefixPattern`:

```
from django.urls import LocalePrefixPattern

pattern = LocalePrefixPattern()

def view(request):
    if not pattern.match(request.resolver_match.route):
        ...
```